# Does anybody know of an MVC framework the works well with ExtJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, xt

I am using ExtJS with a rails backend and would like to use an MVC pattern. Does anyone have any insite on this?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard about [Netzke](http://netzke.org/), but never tried. :)

Petr